# How to change the font for Eclipse Twist scenario editor (Eclipse Plugin - ThoughtWorks Studios)

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am working with Twist as part of developing automatic tests, and I would want to change (decrease size) of the font in the twist scenario editor. I could not find any option in the "Twist" section in the Preferences menu, and the other settings are related to the eclipse editor (e.g. for .java files)

Regards,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Vlad,
Go to Window > Preferences > filter using "font" > click on Colors and Fonts > Look in the basic folder for Text Font > edit

See screencast for demo
http://screencast.com/t/ltf7OZFsZ

-Lars